# iOS: Is the PayPal micropayments option also available in braintree?

Tags: ios, paypal, braintree

For PayPal, a different payment structure can be requested if the average transaction size is below 5$. (This PayPal micropayment option is somewhat under-represented in the help files on the web.)

Does anyone know if a similar change is possible for braintree fees, too?